# Fillbetween two curves in differents axis environments

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I am trying to fill an area between two curves. Easy with `\fillbetween`, right? Except that the two curves are drawn in two distinct axis, so that the `name path` is lost between them.

To get an idea, here is a MWE from `pgfplots`' documentation. Is there an easy way to fill that area?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{set layers}
  \begin{axis}[
   scale only axis,
   xmin=-5,xmax=5,
   axis y line*=left,
   xlabel=$x$,
   ylabel=First ordinate]
   \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[
   scale only axis,
   xmin=-5,xmax=5,
   axis y line*=right,
   axis x line=none,
   ylabel=Second ordinate]
   \addplot[red] {3*x};
   \node[draw,align=center] at (axis cs:1,-5)  {Fill\\here};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `name path global` instead of `name path`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{set layers}
  \begin{axis}[
   scale only axis,
   xmin=-5,xmax=5,
   axis y line*=left,
   xlabel=$x$,
   ylabel=First ordinate]
   \addplot [name path global=a] {x^2};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[
   scale only axis,
   xmin=-5,xmax=5,
   axis y line*=right,
   axis x line=none,
   ylabel=Second ordinate]
   \addplot[red,name path=b] {3*x};
   \node[draw,align=center] at (axis cs:1,-5)  {Fill\\here};
   \addplot [opacity=0.3] fill between[of=a and b];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```